# Remote access to a django application through apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, remote-access

I have a django application served through apache and mod_wsgi and it work perfectly in the host but i cant access to it from a remote machine. I tried with the name of the server and with the ip:port to but any of them works, the last one is just listing the directories in the folder. I check it and the port is open. What should i do?

Comment: We have no way of knowing what the problem is. What is in your apache logs? How have you set up the application?

Comment: Without listings of all your configuration, there's no way anybody will be able to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates you have not set up VirtualHost definitions correctly. What ever external host name you are using isn't mapping to the VirtualHost your application is defined in and it is fall backing to the default (first) VirtualHost definition in the Apache configuration, which is likely set up to use default DocumentRoot. Work out what external host name that Apache sees is an ensure that you have set ServerName/ServerAlias correctly in the VirtualHost for the application.